# Calculating a pattern-match score on a ten-element array

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

I have a method in Python that is extremely slow:

```
def patternRecognition(self):
    patRecStartTime = time.time()
    plotPatAr = []
    patFound = 0

    for eachPattern in self.patternAr:
        sim1 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[0], self.patForRec[0]))

        if sim1 > 50:
            sim2 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[1], self.patForRec[1]))
            if sim2 > 50:
                sim3 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[2], self.patForRec[2]))
                if sim3 > 50 :
                    sim4 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[3], self.patForRec[3]))
                    if sim4 > 50 :
                        sim5 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[4], self.patForRec[4]))
                        if sim5 > 50:
                            sim6 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[5], self.patForRec[5]))
                            if sim6 > 50 :
                                sim7 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[6], self.patForRec[6]))
                                if sim7 > 50 :
                                    sim8 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[7], self.patForRec[7]))
                                    if sim8 > 50:
                                        sim9 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[8], self.patForRec[8]))
                                        if sim9>50:
                                            sim10 = 100.00 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[9], self.patForRec[9]))

                                            howSim = (sim1+sim2+sim3+sim4+sim5+sim6+sim7+sim8+sim9+sim10)/10.00

                                            if howSim > 70:
                                                patFound = 1
                                                plotPatAr.append(eachPattern)


    if patFound == 1:
        for eachPatt in plotPatAr:
            futurePoints = self.patternAr.index(eachPatt)

            if self.performanceAr[futurePoints] > self.patForRec[29]:
                #do something
            else:
                #do something
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on making this method execute quicker? When the array gets to 50,000 elements, it takes about 1 second to execute and increases as the array `patternAr` grows. I read that converting the `for` loop into a map would make it quicker, however, I have not been able to figure it out.

I should mention that `percentChange` is very simple:

```
def percentChange(self, startPoint,currentPoint):
    try:
        x = ((float(currentPoint)-startPoint)/abs(startPoint))*100.00
        if x == 0.0:
            return 0.000000001
        else:
            return x
    except:
        return 0.0001
```

Initial code with sample data [here](https://github.com/tijo45/pythonMachineLearning.git).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Context is very important. Could you elaborate what your function is supposed to do and in what context it's used?

Comment: How much time does each part of the method take, i.e. how much time is spent in the `for eachPattern ...` loop and how much in the `if patFound == 1` part? How many patterns are placed in the `plotPatAr` list?

Comment: What kind of data structure is `self.performanceAt`? It appears to be a dictionary where the keys are lists.

Comment: @ErikR all of the time is spent 'for eachPattern in self.patternAr' once it gets past that, its very quick. This is actually a 30  element array search. I cut it down to 10 to make it paste better.

Comment: @Mast thanks! It's actually a Machine Learning example that I've been playing around with. It's step by step example found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_L9jR8P-54
I can upload the complete code, with the sample data. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: @user1806417 To make the data and code available, if you know how to use git you can just create a github account.

Comment: good suggestion! I've added it to the original post

Answer (score 2):

This whole approach is completely bogus and not worth your time.

A "pattern" is simply an array of percentage changes. For simplicity let's use a pattern size of 5. So a pattern might look like:

```
pat1 = [ 1%, 3%, -2%, 1.6%, 2.1% ]
```

meaning that the price difference (from the price at time 0) at time 1 was 1%, at time 2 was 3%, at time 3 was -2%, etc.

Given another pattern we want to compute how "similar" they are. This is done componentwise using a similarity function for percentages whose definition is:

```
sim(p,q) = 100 - abs (percentageChange(p,q))
```

where `percentageChange` is the percent change between `p` and `q` with an absolute value in the denominator:

```
percentChange(p,q) = 100 * (p-q)/abs(q)
```

So in python, `sim` is:

```
def sim(p,q):
  """Compute the similarity between two percentage changes."""
  pc = 100 * (p-q) / abs(q)
  return 100 - abs(pc)
```

Note since we are multiplying everything by 100 that the `1%` value in `pat1` is just the value 1, not the conventional 0.01.

Given two patterns, `pat1` and `pat2`, we say they are *close* if

```
sim( pat1[i], pat2[i] ) >= 70   for each i in 0..4
```

## The big idea

The idea behind these patterns and similarity measures is that given historical data we compute a pattern and a future price change with the idea that the pattern implies the future price change.

Then given current data we compute the current pattern and search for a similar pattern in our database from which we can deduce the corresponding price change.

The main problem is that the `sim` function is not symmetrical in its arguments, i.e. `sim(p,q)` and `sim(q,p)` may have wildly different values.
Consider these examples:

```
sim(1.200, 2.000)   = 60.000000
sim(2.000, 1.200)   = 33.333333

sim(-1.000, 2.000)  = -50.000000
sim(2.000, -1.000)  = -200.000000

sim(-1.000, -2.000) = 50.000000
sim(-2.000, -1.000) = 0.000000

sim(-1.000, 1.000)  = -100.000000  # guess these are actually the same!
sim(1.000, -1.000)  = -100.000000

sim(-1.000, -0.100) = -800.000000
sim(-0.100, -1.000) = 10.000000

sim(-1.000, 0.100) = -1000.000000
sim(0.100, -1.000) = -10.000000
```

A better definition for `sim(p,q)` would simply be:

```
sim(p,q) = abs(p-q)
```

and then to define two patterns to be close if

```
sum of sim(pat1[i], pat2[i]) for i in 0..4
  is LESS THAN a certain number
```

The prediction algorithm then boils down to a nearest neighbor search in a high number of dimensions (e.g. the length of the pattern array.)

Comment: ErikR thanks for the reply! I'm not using this to trade, I'm using it to learn python with a real problem. That's how I learn best :) Thats why my initial question was around the performance difference between for-loop and changing it to map :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to write the main loop in a more concise way. It won't necessarily execute any quicker, though:

```
  for eachPattern in self.patternAr:
    totalSim = 0
    for i in range(0,10):
      sim = 100 - abs(self.percentChange(eachPattern[i]), sef.patForRec[i])
      totalSim += sim
      if sim <= 50:
        break
    if i >= 10:
      howSim = totalSim / 10.00
      if homSim > 70
        patFound = 1
        plotPatAr.append(eachPattern)
```

One thing this approach makes possible, however, is that we can substitute the `percentChange` function with one that is tailored for this computation.

For instance, since we are only checking if the percent change is > 50, we can skip the `if x == 0` check. Moreover, we can also inline the call to avoid the cost of method dispatching:

```
    ...
    for i in range(0,10):
      if eachPattern[i] == 0:
        sim = 100 - 0.0001
      else:
        p = float(self.patForRec[i])
        if eachPattern[i] == p:
          sim = 100 - 0.000000001
        else:
          sim = 100 - (p - eachPattern[i])/abs(eachPattern[i]) * 100
      totalSim += sim
      if sim <= 50:
        break
    ...
```

The checking of `eachPattern[i]` against 0 serves the same purpose of the `try...except...` block in `percentChange`.

Note: If there is a way to rule out those patterns which have a zero somewhere then you can skip the check `if eachPattern[i] == 0`

Finally, another thing to note is that you are calling `float(self.patForRec[i])` multiple times - once for each of your 50,000 patterns. I would do that conversion outside the loop like this:

```
floatPatForRec = [ float(self.patForRec[i]) for i in range(0,10) ]
```

and then in the main loop use `floatPatForRec[i]`:

```
...
for i in range(0,10):
  if eachPattern[i] == 0:
    sim = 100 - 0.0001
  else:
    if eachPattern[i] == floatPatForRec[i]:
      sim = 100 - 0.000000001
    else:
      sim = 100 - (floatPatForRec[i] - eachPattern[i]) / eachPattern[i])*100
...
```

Comment: PEP 8 specifies four-space indentation, as the original code did correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm going to try and implement the changes and report back.

Comment: Trying to inline the percentChange didn't help. It caused the processing time to go up to : 
CurrentPattern took: 4.41074371338e-05
Pattern loop took: 0.407335996628
Pattern patternRecognition took: 0.407351970673
From: 
CurrentPattern took: 3.981590271e-05
Pattern loop took: 0.193712949753
Pattern patternRecognition took: 0.193730831146

Comment: This guy's idea is a waste of time - see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more advice based on this part of your code:

```
...
                                        if howSim > 70:
                                            patFound = 1
                                            plotPatAr.append(eachPattern)


if patFound == 1:
    for eachPatt in plotPatAr:
        futurePoints = self.patternAr.index(eachPatt)
...
```

The method `.index` is relative slow but indexing using `[]` is very quick. Instead of appending each wanted pattern and then calling `.index` to find it again, just append the index to `plotPatAr`:

```
for i in xrange(len[self.patternAr]):
    eachPattern = self.patternAr[i]
...
     if howSim > 70:
       plotPatAr.append(i)
...
if plotPatAr:
  for i in plotPatAr:
    futurePoints = self.patternAr[i]
    ...
```

Now you've avoided the possibly expensive `.index` method call.